# Vostro 220 can't get CPU off motherboard

Tags: cpu, motherboard, dell-vostro

I can't seem to get the CPU off the motherboard to replace the motherboard. I've unscrewed the 4 screws on the outside but it just is stuck there. I've pulled and pulled but still nothing. I don't want to yank too hard and risk damaging the CPU. Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by "4 screws on the outside" to get the CPU off the motherboard. Maybe upload a picture. That Vostro model uses a latching system. Are you talking about the fan on the heat sink?

Here is the [service manual](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/vos220/en/sm/index.htm) for that model on the Dell website, and the instructions for [CPU removal are here](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/vos220/en/sm/cpu.htm#wp1192480).